# Jmeter construct dynamic http request body

Tags: groovy, jmeter

Could anyone please guide me how do I construct a dynamic json http request body based on the # of ids that were stored in a list? Below is an example of required request body:
[sample request body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiJrn.png)
I had a JSR223 script in place to collect IDs and store them in a list. Below is part of my script (post processor) to pass each id in the list to the http request body.

```
for (int j=0; j < myList.size(); j++) {
vars.put(“accountId”, qualifiedList[j])
```

}

And below is the structure of HTTP request body:
[HTTP request body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxc9C.png)

The issue I had was that with this configuration, only the last id in the list was passed to the body... So how do I construct a dynamic json payload that contains all ids as the example request body?

Answer (score 0):

1. Each iteration of the [for loop](http://grails.asia/groovy-for-loop-examples) you're overwriting the `accountId` variable value with the new value from your `qualifiedList`
2. You're supposed to produce a [JSON Array](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp) and you're generating a single String

Suggested code change:

```
def payload = []

for (int j = 0; j < myList.size(); j++) {
    payload.add([accountId: qualifiedList[j]])
}

vars.put("accountId", new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(payload).toPrettyString())
```

More information:

- [JsonBuilder](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)